# how to let docker container work with sshuttle?

Tags: dns, docker, vpn

I need container be able to use sshuttle tool.
I try either way in host or containner. But none of it will work.
Here's what I need:
I run : `sshuttle -r mysshaccount@my.remote.server --dns 0/0`  in host. It can help host application access internet via sshuttle. But for container, it can't resolve the DNS request. It seems --dns will affect container's DNS capability. how to make container work with host's sshuttle?

also if I run sshuttle inside the container. It seems container don't have the permission with `"--dns"` option in sshuttle.

anyway, I need this option `"--dns"` in container because it's the only way to get over government fire wall (GFW) in china.

anyone help to make it work?

Answer (score 25):

Try `sshuttle -l 0.0.0.0 --dns -vvr XXXXXX@YY.YY.YY.YY 0/0`, that works for me. I guess we need `-l 0.0.0.0` so that docker containers with "remote ip" can connect to the tunnel.

Comment: I believe this is correct, ``-l 0.0.0.0`` is required at least for the nat method because incoming packets get redirected (by iptables) to "the primary address of the incoming interface" [``man iptables-extensions``] which implies we must be listening on this address.

Comment: This used to work well. But, this solution stopped working for the recent Docker versions. In my test, "Docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56" can no longer benefit from this tunneling set up.

Comment: One thing I found out was: make sure you disable the firewall. On Ubuntu, use "sudo ufw disable"

Answer (score 13):

Normally, setting `0.0.0.0` entails listening on externally available interfaces, and this is [also the case with sshuttle](https://sshuttle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manpage.html#cmdoption-sshuttle-l) .

A more secure approach would be the following - on your host:

1. launch your "normal" `sshuttle` instance, listening on localhost,
2. **launch another `sshuttle` instance, listening on your docker host's** virtual network interface.

For example:

```
sshuttle --dns -r <your-ssh-server> 0/0
sshuttle -l 172.17.0.1 --dns -r <your-ssh-server> 0/0
```

Note that this will interfere with host <-> container communication (such as port binding), but it will allow for secure outside connections for your containers (you can further help yourself with excluding Docker's subnet, e.g. with `-x 172.17.0.0/24`).

Comment: This solution, opening two sshutlle is what worked for me, BUT I had to run the first sshutle as root, and the second as user in docker group.

Answer (score 5):

you can see your network bridge subnets and exclude it in sshuttle
e.g,

```
sudo sshuttle -l 0.0.0.0:0 -r user@host -x host -x 127.0.0.1 -x 172.21.0.0/24 -x 172.22.0.0/24 -x 172.23.0.0/24 0/0 --dns
```

Comment: to find the network bridge, first get the network_id list via `docker network ls`, then using the specific network_id execute `docker network inspect network_id` to find the subnet